# Why integral is equal to zero

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, estimation

I wonder why under assumption that w>>$\frac{1}{T}$ then $\int_{0}^{T} sin(wt)dt$ is approximately zero?

Since the integral should be like- $\frac{cos(wt)}{w}$ from $0$ to $T$ and after plugging the valued we will end up with :

$\frac{-cos(wT)+1}{w}$

Comment: The quantity $\frac{1-\cos(wT)}{w}$ has most likely been *neglected* because the characteristic time of the problem is $T$ and $\frac{1}{w}<<T$.

Comment: Yes. I edited my question to be approximately zero but why ? T can be 1000 and w can be 1. Then the integral still can not be approximated to  zero.

Comment: I think one must interpred $>>$ in the sense of limits. I also suggest to consider $T$ as fixed. So, the integral tends to zero as $w\to+\infty$ is what is meant by saying that the integral is almost zero when $w>>1/T$. This can be quantified if necessary (using the expression you have for the integral).

Comment: Physicists sometimes use the sloppy notion of an term to be "approximately zero" to express the fact that that term (possibly under certain conditions like parameters being very large or small) will become so small that it can be neglected compared to other relevant terms in - say - a sum. Maybe that is the case for your integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a notation commonly employed by physicists to say you need to take limits: the estimate is given by the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit, in this case more like $M-\delta$:
\begin{equation}
\forall M >0\ \exists \delta=\delta(M)>0: wT>M\Rightarrow\frac{-cos(wT)+1}{w}<\delta
\end{equation}
that is, your approximation gets more and more precise as you get "closer" to $\infty$. In your example of $w=1$ and $T=1000$ you get something of order $1$ as the result of your integral. If you were in a laboratory trying to measure something relating to this formula and wanted something closer to zero, you would just need to set an higher $T$ or $w$ - that's what this formula is telling you.
Hope this helps. :-)

(Also, for computing the limit:
\begin{equation}
\frac{-cos(wT)+1}{w}=\frac{(-cos(wT)+1)}{wT}T
\end{equation}
even if I guess this wasn't really your problem)

Comment: Thanks. The only problem is what if T also is very large meaning $\frac{1-cos(wT}{wT}$ is very small due to $wT>>1$ but $T$ is also very big so still the result won't go to zero.